# Display total sale from sum of datagrid column in C# WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, sum

[image]

I am having trouble understanding how to bind the total sale textbox on the UI to the sum of the total price in the datagrid. I have read several articles, tried to implement a sum procedure and bind it, tried using collection changed notification and I can't get the total sale to work. I have an item class that has a Quantity and UnitPrice properties with a calculated TotalPrice which automatically updates when quantity or unit price changes. The list of items is contained in a SalesOrder class. The ui is the main window which I am using to create the order.
My code is at: https://github.com/battondl/SalesOrder/tree/master/simpleShoppingListProgram
Any guidance on how to get to get the total price on the UI textbox to update automatically would be much appreciated.

Each line item in the datagrid has a total price based on quanity * unit price.

It is the Total Sale price that I am trying to update which is a sum of all the line items totalprice.

```
class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string partNumber;
    private int quantity;
    private decimal unitPrice;
    private DateTime orderDate;


    public string PartNumber
    {
        get { return partNumber; }
        set
        {
            partNumber = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Quantity
    {
        get { return quantity; }
        set
        {
            quantity = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Quantity");
            OnPropertyChanged("TotalPrice");
        }
    }
    public decimal UnitPrice
    {
        get { return unitPrice; }
        set
        {
            unitPrice = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("UnitPrice");
            OnPropertyChanged("TotalPrice");
        }
    }

    public DateTime OrderDate
    {
        get { return orderDate; }
        set
        {
            orderDate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public decimal TotalPrice => Quantity * UnitPrice;

    public Item()
    {
        PartNumber = "";
        Quantity = 0;
        UnitPrice = 0.00m;
        OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
        }
    }


}



class SalesOrder 
{

    private string orderNumber;
    public string OrderNumber
    {
        get { return orderNumber; }
        set
        {
            orderNumber = value;
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Item> items;

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get { return items; }
    }

    public SalesOrder()
    {
        orderNumber = "";
        items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

    }

    public decimal CalculateTotalPrice()
    {
        decimal total = 0.00m;
        foreach (Item item in items)
        {
            total += item.TotalPrice;
        }
        return total;
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private SalesOrder salesOrder;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        salesOrder = new SalesOrder();
        dgSaleItems.ItemsSource = salesOrder.Items;

        tbx_totalSale.Text = salesOrder.CalculateTotalPrice().ToString();
    }
}


<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
        Grid.Row="0">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="OrderNumber: " />
            <TextBox Name="tbx_orderNumber" 
                     Width="100"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                Grid.Row="1">
        <DataGrid Name="dgSaleItems"
        Grid.Row="1"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="partNumber"
                                    Header="Part Number"
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=PartNumber}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="quantity"
                                    Header="Quantity"
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=Quantity}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="unitPrice"
                                    Header="Unit Price"
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=UnitPrice}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="totalPrice"
                                    Header="Total Price"
                                    Binding="{Binding Path=TotalPrice}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="orderDate"
                                        Header="Order Date">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=OrderDate}"          />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=OrderDate}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                Grid.Row="7">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Total Sale: " />
            <TextBox x:Name="tbx_totalSale"
                     Width="100"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Put the relevant code in the question please. Also explain the difference between "total sale" and `TotalPrice`, if any. If they're the same, what is the problem you are trying to solve? If they're different, why don't you do both the same way?

Comment: I don't see any binding on the txtbox at all... posting the code would help...

Comment: The total price is per line item calculated by quantity * unit price. I also took out the non working binding as it did not work. The total sale is a sum of all the line items total price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
> {
>     salesOrder = new SalesOrder();
>     dgSaleItems.ItemsSource = salesOrder.Items;
>     
>     tbx_totalSale.Text = salesOrder.CalculateTotalPrice().ToString();
> }
> ```

You are only updating the total sale once during the window load event, but you forget you also have to update it every time an item's quantity or price is changed.

Here's how you can do that:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    salesOrder = new SalesOrder();
    dgSaleItems.ItemsSource = salesOrder.Items;

    salesOrder.Items.CollectionChanged += (s, args) =>
    {
        if (args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            foreach (Item item in args.OldItems)
            {
                item.PropertyChanged -= UpdateTotalSale;
            }
        }
        else if (args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach (Item item in args.NewItems)
            {
                item.PropertyChanged += UpdateTotalSale;
            }
        }

        UpdateTotalSale(this, default);
    };
}

private void UpdateTotalSale(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    tbx_totalSale.Text = salesOrder.CalculateTotalPrice().ToString();
}
```

Ideally, you should implement `INPC` on `SalesOrder`, and move the above code inside `SalesOrder`, as the code behind should be kept as clean as possible.

Comment: Thanks, you provided the assistance I needed to finish bringing it all together. I also was able to figure out how to implement it into the SalesOrder class as you suggested!

Comment: i had a problem with this way , when deleting rows from my datagrid it does not update the totalPrice .. any idea ?

Comment: @RAMM-HDR You also need to call `UpdateTotalSale` when the item gets added/removed.

Answer (score 1):

There's no binding in your text box:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbx_totalSale"
                 Width="100"/>
```

It needs to be:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbx_totalSale"
         Text="{Binding TotalSale}"
                 Width="100"/>
```

and you need to add a `TotalSale` property to your `SaleOrder` class that returns the sum of the lines:

```
public decimal TotalSale
{
    get { return items.Sum(i => i.TotalPrice);
}
```

You will need to publish an `OnPropertyChanged("TotalSale")` event when items are added to or removed from the collection or when then `TotalPrice` of a line changes. You are already updating `TotalPrice` when either the quantity or unit price changes, so all you need to do is propagate that change upwards through the `items` collection.

Comment: This works, but only once. You need to subscribe to items' property changed as well and notify when `TotalSale` should be changed.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 - indeed.

Comment: Thanks, I wish I could flag more than one answer, it was a combination of both answers that helped me get it together.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Thanks, I have it working now!

I've modified/added the follow to the SalesOrder class

```
  public decimal TotalSale
  {
      get { return items.Sum(i => i.TotalPrice); }

  }

  public SalesOrder()
  {
      orderNumber = "";
      items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

      Items.CollectionChanged += (s, args) =>
      {
          if (args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
          {
              foreach (Item item in args.OldItems)
              {
                  item.PropertyChanged -= UpdateTotalSale;
              }
          }
          else if (args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
          {
              foreach (Item item in args.NewItems)
              {
                  item.PropertyChanged += UpdateTotalSale;
              }
          }
      };

  }

  private void UpdateTotalSale(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            if (window.GetType() == typeof(MainWindow))
            {
                (window as MainWindow).tbx_totalSale.Text =           CalculateTotalPrice().ToString();
            }
        }

    }
```

I also added the following to the xaml.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                Grid.Row="7">
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Total Sale: " />
            <TextBox x:Name="tbx_totalSale"
                     Text="{Binding TotalSale}"
                     Width="100"
                     x:FieldModifier="public"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And finally, this to the code behind:

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     salesOrder = new SalesOrder();
     dgSaleItems.ItemsSource = salesOrder.Items;

 }
```